# Erase using brush in GLPaint

Tags: iphone

As part of modifying the `GLPaint`, I am trying to add erase functionality where user could select an eraser button and erase the painted area just as painting.

I am trying have a conditional statement within `"renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end"` method so that I could check whether the stroke is for painting or erasing.

For erasing I do not know how to make use of the "`start`" and "`end`" parameters for erasing. Is there any method call in OpenGL like `glClear()` that accepts these two parameter and does erase?

Any pointer will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: yes it is, the answer given by zlog works in my painting app

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Along the same vein as [Erase using brush in GLPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048811/erase-using-brush-in-glpaint/4654350#4654350), you could reuse the

```
- (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
```

method by having the condition:

```
if (isEraserBrushType) {
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
    glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
} else {
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    [self setBrushColorWithRed:brushColourRed green:brushColourGreen blue:brushColourBlue];
}
```

above the code:

```
// Render the vertex array
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, eraseBuffer);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);
```

Note, you'll need to implement isEraserBrushType, and store brushColourRed, brushColourGreen and brushColourBlue somehow.

Comment: it erases with a rectangle brush (i think it the brush image size - 64/64), not with the current brush image. any ideas why is that?

Comment: I'm guessing that's why this isn't an accepted answer. @zlog I'd like to know this as well. Any idea how to erase with the brush image, not the brush bounding box?

Comment: just found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074955/blending-a-texture-to-erase-alpha-values-softly-with-opengl using `glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I think I can solve this problem, although not a very good.

You can create a new function copy of "renderLineFromPoint", like this;

```
- (void) drawErase:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end
{
    static GLfloat*     eraseBuffer = NULL;
    static NSUInteger   eraseMax = 64;

    NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
    count,
    i;

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

    // Convert locations from Points to Pixels
    CGFloat scale = 1.0;//self.contentScaleFactor;
    start.x *= scale;
    start.y *= scale;
    end.x *= scale;
    end.y *= scale;

    // Allocate vertex array buffer
    if(eraseBuffer == NULL)
        eraseBuffer = malloc(eraseMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

    // Add points to the buffer so there are drawing points every X pixels      
    count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);

    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(vertexCount == eraseMax) {
            eraseMax = 2 * eraseMax;
            eraseBuffer = realloc(eraseBuffer, eraseMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
        }

        eraseBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        eraseBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
        vertexCount += 1;
    }
    //}
    //glEnable(GL_BLEND);   //   打开混合
        //glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   //   关闭深度测试
        //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,   GL_ONE);   //   基于源象素alpha通道值的半透明混合函数 

        //You need set the mixed-mode
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);
        //the erase brush color  is transparent.
    glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 0.0);

    // Render the vertex array
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, eraseBuffer);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);

    // Display the buffer
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];

        // at last restore the  mixed-mode
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

My English is poor. Can you understand what I said?
Hope these can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to use the accepted answer, however it would erase in a square pattern, whereas I wanted to erase using my own brush. Instead I used a different blending function.

```
if (self.isErasing) {
    glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    [self setBrushColorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0];
} else {
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

The way this works is that the incoming (source) colour is multiplied by *zero* to completely disappear meaning that you don't actually paint anything new. Then the destination colour is set to be (1 - Source Alpha). So wherever the brush *has* colour the destination has *no* colour.

Answer (score -2):

Another idea, if suppose your view's back ground is pure black you can simply call [`self setBrushColorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0]` and then call renderPoint:ToPint: - This will draw in black (and the user may think that he is actually erasing.